# How to store a collection of data in a class where there is a nested collection in that data from Firebase in Java?

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Ok, so the title may be a bit ambiguous or difficult to understand so I will try to make this as detailed as possible. I am writing an android application in which I have users.

The json in firebase looks like this:

```
user{
   $auid{
      "Name": "blah",
      "email": "blah",
      "image": "blah",
      "conversationKeys"{
                         "randKey":"key",
                         "randKey":"key",
                         "randKey":"key",
                        }
                 }
}
```

So the issue I am having is the nested collection (conversation keys) which are keys to conversations in a whole different collection.  I do not know how to store them in the user java class I have.  I had tried making the value in the class an arrayList, hoping that it would just work.

I use this to retrieve the data:

```
userRef = new Firebase((new FireBaseAPI()).getUsersURL()+"/"+sharedPrefs.getAuthuid());
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
user = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserData.class);
}
```

I want to beable to store it all in one class in which the conversation keys are stored in an arrayList or array or whatever.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If more clarity is required do not hesitate.  Thank you for your help.

Also, the user data class is:

```
    public class UserData {

    public String displayName;
    public String profileImageURL;
    public String coverImageURL;
    public String lastLogin;
    public String provider;
    public String bio;
    public ArrayList<String> conversationKeys;

    public ArrayList<String> getConversationKeys() {
        return conversationKeys;
    }

    public void setConversationKeys(ArrayList<String> conversationKeys) {
        this.conversationKeys = conversationKeys;
    }

    public UserData(String name,
                    String profilePic,
                    String coverPic) {

        this.displayName = name;
        this.profileImageURL = profilePic;
        this.coverImageURL = coverPic;
    }

    public UserData() {

    }

    public String getBio() {
        return bio;
    }

    public void setBio(String bio) {
        this.bio = bio;
    }

    public String getProvider() {
        return provider;
    }

    public void setProvider(String provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public String getLastLogin() {
        return lastLogin;
    }



    public void setLastLogin(String lastLogin) {
        this.lastLogin = lastLogin;
    }

    public String getProfileImageURL() {
        return profileImageURL;
    }

    public void setProfileImageURL(String profileImageURL) {
        this.profileImageURL = profileImageURL;
    }

    public String getCoverImageURL() {
        return coverImageURL;
    }

    public void setCoverImageURL(String coverImageURL) {
        this.coverImageURL = coverImageURL;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }


    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer below. Next time, can you please ensure that the JSON you show matches the Java class you're showing? It has the added advantage that we can't have any difference in interpretation of things like `blah` and `randKey`. You can easily get (some of the) JSON from your Firebase database by using the Export button in the dashboard.

Comment: Sure thing and thank you very much for your response, I should have realized it needed to go into a Map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversation keys are stored as key/value pairs, not as an array. 
So you'll need to retrieve them into a `Map` (instead of the array/list you are trying to get).

For the `conversationKeys` property in the JSON, add this to your class:

```
public class UserData {
    ...
    private Map<String,String> conversationKeys;

    public Map<String,String> getConversationKeys() {
        return conversationKeys;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Frank!
  Is it possible to make application using Java (Spring framework) along with Firebase as a database and to host over Google App Engine ..?